# Deploy WPF Application with .NET Runtime already within to avoid user having to download it by itself?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, windows-installer

I'm developing a WPF App (using .NET CORE). But everytime I have to install it in a computer that doesn't have .NET Runtime installed, it opens a dialog box in installation asking for the user to download it. And it's a super messy website with a lot of things for the user to install, so it's kinda not ideal to ask the users to install it by themselves.

For creating a installer, i'm using: [Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects 2022](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2022InstallerProjects)

The website for installing .NET Runtime that the installer redirects you is the following: [Download .NET Core 3.1](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/3.1) (Note that the common user won't know if it is a console app or a desktop app, and it's super confusing for the user).

So, is there a way to already incorporate the .NET Runtime inside my compiled WPF App? So the user doesn't have to download it by itself?

Comment: You would publish the app as self-container. However, once you do that then it's the responsibility of your application to apply monthly security and quality patches as it won't use any version installed on the local computer that Windows Update might otherwise patch: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-cli#self-contained-deployment

Comment: @MartinCostello If I don't release these security patches would the user's computer be vulnerable or only my Application would be subjected to be "hacked" (Like bypassing the login page of my app or something...)?

Comment: Depends entirely on what security issues may or may not occur in the future.